# How to foreach model to views on fuelphp

Tags: orm, model, fuelphp

i have Model_User

```
 // Get Exams by User
public static function get_exam_by_user($user_id) {
    $query = "SELECT e.exam_id, e.exam_code, e.exam_name, e.description, e.creator, e.password,
              e.max_attempt, e.random_order, e.max_time, e.max_score, e.min_score, e.grading, 
              e.created_at, e.updated_at
              FROM exam e, user_exam ue
              WHERE ue.exam_id = e.exam_id
              AND ue.status = 1
              AND ue.user_id = :user_id";
    $result = DB::query($query)->bind('user_id', $user_id)->execute();
    return $result->as_array();
}
```

and this controller

```
public function action_index() {
    $data = array();
    //$data['user_id'] = \Auth\Auth::get('id');
    //$data['username'] = \Auth\Auth::get('username');
    $user_id = Auth\Auth::get('id');
    //$data['exams'] = Model_Exam::find('all');
    $data['exams'] = Model_Exam::get_exam_by_user($user_id);
    $this->template->title = "Exams";
    $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/exam/index', $data);
}
```

How to foreach to views ?i try to printr_r

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [exam_id] => 2 [exam_code] => SD_K1S1_MAT [exam_name] => Ujian Matematika SD Kelas 1 Sem 1 [description] => [creator] => RF [password] => [max_attempt] => 3 [random_order] => 1 [max_time] => 60 [max_score] => 100 [min_score] => 0 [grading] => [created_at] => 2013 [updated_at] => 2013 ) [1] => Array ( [exam_id] => 2 [exam_code] => SD_K1S1_MAT [exam_name] => Ujian Matematika SD Kelas 1 Sem 1 [description] => [creator] => RF [password] => [max_attempt] => 3 [random_order] => 1 [max_time] => 60 [max_score] => 100 [min_score] => 0 [grading] => [created_at] => 2013 [updated_at] => 2013 ) )
```

if you can help solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do something like this :

```
<?php foreach ($exams as $exam):
echo $exam['exam_id'];
    echo $exam['exam_code'];
echo $exam['exam_name']; .... and so on....
```

Hope is what you need.

Comment: Ok, I'll be glad if you also accept (up-vote) the answer too :)

Comment: Looks like a 'hit and run' questioner here, I upvoted you one for the effort.